# How to create Pod framework with dependent Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

I want to create a new pod framework with a Firebase dependency but when I run:

```
pod lib lint
```

The following error occurs:

> - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:1:9: fatal error: 'FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h' file not found`

this is "**PushSDK.podspec**":

[image]

Comment: Add `'Firebase/Analytics'` to the dependencies? Also, I'm not sure if you can put various dependencies that way or have to put them into one line.

Answer (score 4):

add the follwoing lines in podspec file worked for me.

i get this from [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6526)

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
"OTHER_LDFLAGS" => '$(inherited) -framework "FirebaseCore" -framework "FirebaseMessaging"',
"CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES" => 'YES',
"FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => '$(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCore/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks"'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with CocoaPods 1.1.1 and the following Podspec. It passed pod lib lint without issue.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'StackO-Dependency-Demo'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'A demo of Dependency in a Podspec.'    
  s.description      = <<-DESC
This pod demonstrates including dependencies to other Pods in a developed-pod.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/ericwastaken/CocoaPod-Dependency-Demo'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Some Dev' => 'somedev985635214@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/ericwastaken/CocoaPod-Dependency-Demo.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/ericwastaken'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source_files = 'StackO-Dependency-Demo/Classes/**/*'

  # s.resource_bundles = {
  #   'StackO-Dependency-Demo' => ['StackO-Dependency-Demo/Assets/*.png']
  # }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  s.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 3.0.1'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Core'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

My results:

```
EricWkSta:StackO-Dependency-Demo eric$ pod lib lint

 -> StackO-Dependency-Demo
 -> StackO-Dependency-Demo (0.1.0)

StackO-Dependency-Demo passed validation.
```

Could it be a bug in an older version of CocoaPods?